Creating a custom flow for D365 using power apps
I've created a application for D365 in my power apps enviornment. This application is called Projects its based of a table of the same name that has a many-to-many relationship with accounts and contacts. I've also created a custom button and I want to link a process/workflow to that button that will create a quick campaign for both the accounts and contacts related to that project entity.
I'vew tried to work it out in power apps but the farthest I have gotten is having a process that does a campaign and launches a campaign activity but I do not see a way in power apps to connect that activity to a account/contact related to the project. I've also tried to use power automate but I do not think any of the dataverse options will work.

You can achieve this in few steps.

Set up a button on Ribbon to initiate the process. You can use RibbonWorkbench tool by XRMToolBox to do this.

Link this button to a command with a JavaScript Library function and pass the primary Control.




Add your JavaScript function to Send request to an HTTP Triggered power automate flow. Add the URL to this function



function callHttpFunction(recordId) {
var formContext = primaryControl; // Using primaryControl directly as the form context
var recordId = formContext.data.entity.getId();
  var url = "Replace this URL with the actual endpoint of your HTTP function";
  var data = JSON.stringify({
    recordId: recordId
  });

  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("POST", url, true);
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    alert("Sync started successfully.");
  };
  req.send(data);
}




Once done, Head on to your PowerAutomate flow. I have used a record from 'Orders' entity to create an email campaign for related accounts using PA. You must create an email message first using a "Add a Row" connector.


